# Anyone know PayPal Standard method provide Recurring functionality or not?

Tags: paypal, payment

Anyone know PayPal Standard method provide Recurring functionality or not?
I want to modify Grand Total of PayPal Standard payment method, when we place order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so, this is what I found [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/working-with-recurring-profiles)

> Currently, by default, Magento supports purchasing items with
>   recurring profiles only for the PayPal payment system and only through
>   the **Express Checkout** method.